# does idm remove temp file when you remove it from download list?

Tags: download-manager

i just wanted to remove completed downloads from internet download manager list that by mistake i removed the downloading file with 25 gig size. i want to know is it possible to recover and resume download of that file or that is gone and i have to start from beginning?

thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's gone

Files that large don't even make it to recycle bin and gets permanently deleted

Comment: if it was shorter size could it be recovered? if yes how it could be?

Comment: my maximum size of recycle bin is about 30 gigi